# How to fix position of layer with CSS while maintaining minimum height?

Tags: html, css

I have a two column layout, where the left side consists out of a menu that should stick and the right side contains a long form. On the bottom  of the page is a footer:

[image]

There are two problems with this:

1. If the browser window is smaller then the menu height, it is not possible to see the lower menu items as it is fixed and therefore does not scroll.
2. If one scrolls down the form to the bottom, the menu will hide the footer

[image]

My CSS looks like this:

```
#menu_side{
    color:black;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin:67px 5px 5px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
}
```

As an alternative mentioned inside the comments, one could use a container for the menu and use vh. Unfortunately this seems not to work as the inner elements simply outgrow the div. Illustrated in this img with a red border for the container:

[image]

How could I manage to keep the menu in sight of the user while he scrolls down the form and in the same time solve the mentioned 2 problems? Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: Please post a working code snippet that reproduces your issue

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap `#menu_side` in a new container and let that container be `fixed` and make sure its `height` equals the viewport height. This can be done with `vh` units or with Javascript.

```
<div class="menu_container">
    <div id="menu_side">
        <!-- your menu -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu_container{
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 260px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#menu_side{
  margin:67px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

As for your second issue: This can best be achieved using Javascript. You could for instance calculate the visible height of the footer element and use Javascript to calculate the appropriate height for `.menu-container`

Comment: This seems not to work. I have edited the question explaining the result.

Comment: what's the containers `overflow` set to?

Comment: It is not defined, therefore default. However, I also tried "scroll"

Comment: @merlin and `#menu_slide` is positioned `static` (default)?